# Binding Image.Source to System.Drawing.Image not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'm generating a `System.Drawing.Image` object which I set to my bound ViewModel property.
I know the image is being generated correctly, but it is not showing in the WPF form. Is `System.Drawing.Image` not a compatible source type for this?

```
Image image = GetMyGeneratedImage();

var vm = _myViewModelFactory.CreateExport().Value;
vm.MyImage= image;

if (vm.ShowDialog(ShellView))
..
```

ViewModel code:

```
private System.Drawing.Image _myImage;

public Image MyImage
{
   get { return _myImage; }
   set { _myImage= value; }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding MyImage}"/>
```

Comment: I think with WPF, you will need to use an instance of `BitmapSource`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF `Image` control's source doesn't support `System.Drawing.Image`. You'll have to convert it to `BitmapSource` and there is no built in method available for this conversion.

But the solution is available:

```
   [DllImport("gdi32")]
   static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

   public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
   {
       IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
       BitmapSource bs = null;
       try
       {
           bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip, 
              IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, 
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
       }
       finally
       {
           DeleteObject(ip);
       }

       return bs;
   }
```

Reference: http://khason.net/blog/how-to-use-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap-in-wpf/

Comment: thanks, this worked. I tried several other solutions using MemoryStream but the image wasn't rendered properly. Are you aware of why these built in methods don't work?

Comment: Sorry I've never tried any other solution, so I am not aware of it

Comment: Ah. I thought that's what you meant by "and there is no built in method available for this conversion."

Comment: Well ! by that sentence I meant that there's no method exists in `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` which takes `System.Drawing.Bitmap` as parameter and returns `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`. All the solutions are created by developers, and I've tried only this one.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for clearing that up. I was hoping to find a method outside of using interop, since it's caused problems for me in the past, but the other solutions that didn't use it also did not work. Thanks again for the answer.